# Zoom in on an iFrame's CONTENT

Tags: jquery, html, flash, zooming

I am trying to zoom in (NOT CHANGE THE SIZE) of an iFrame, where the source is a SWF file.

```
<iframe src="http://ray.eltania.net/TEST/swf-play/swf/testMotion.swf" width="600px" height="500px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MuxRX/

As you can see, the size of the iFrame is 600x500px. I would like to zoom in on the CONTENT of that SWF. Imagine zooming in 90%, then you would only see the slider once in a while, but keep the same size of the frame.

I tried every link on StackOverflow, but every result just changed the size of the content, where I want a zoom effect. I do not want stuff like this:

```
iframe {
    zoom: 0.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MuxRX/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Iframe comes from a different domain, you can't. That would be a cross-site scripting attack, which would be blocked by the browser.

Comment: So let's imagine that there is a 1000x1000px sized SWF file, but only the center's 100x100px is being used. Am I stuck with the giant white area then?

Comment: Yes. You cannot manipulate iframe content from someone else's site.

Comment: That's a shame. What if I inject jQuery code into the iFrame after load? Like **$("iframe").next("embed").css("width","150%");** ?

Comment: You are willing to try. The Same Origin Policy will prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Workaround like this

**HTML**

```
<iframe class="zoom" src="http://something"></iframe> <!-- add class zoom to iframe -->
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 0;
}
.zoom {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */ 
  transform: scale(2); /* zoom factor - prefix if needed */
  width: 200px; /* half of iframe width */
  height: 200px; /* half of iframe height */
  margin: 100px 0 0 100px; /* reposition iframe */
  overflow: hidden; /* remove big-ass scrollbars */
}
```

Comment: Just want to note, as encouragement to a new(ish) user, that the suggestion to add `-webkit-transform: scale(2);` as a fix for Safari and Chrome comes courtesy of a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3852289) from [SirBT](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2811672/sirbt).